# Are these terms different?

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference between *aspect* and *aspectuality*? Do these words have the same meaning?

Comment: Well, *aspect* is a real word, with several different meanings, depending on context.  *Aspectual* is a bit of jargon used by grammar theorists.  (Hint: consult a dictionary, or at least Google the terms.)

Comment: No. "Aspect" can mean a lot of things. "Aspectuality" means exactly nothing.

Answer (score 1):

*Aspect* means a feature (with various technical meanings in astrology, astronomy, architecture, and grammar).  *Aspectual* means of or relating to an aspect.  Thus *aspectuality* means the field or state or property of those things that may be described as *aspectual*.

In grammar, the **aspect** of a verb form is the relationship that verb has to the flow of time.  Some examples of aspect are the *continuous* ("I am eating"), the *habitual* ("I used to eat"), and *terminative* ("I finished eating).

The *continuous*, the *habitual*, and the *terminative* are **aspectual**  characteristics of verbs.

**Aspectuality** is the name for the property of aspectual characteristics.